# creating an element in javascript and then use jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a noty via javascript where I used several elements in:

```
                       var n = noty({
                    layout: 'centerRight',
                    theme: "defaultTheme",
                    text: "<img class='item' src='images/emark.png' width='30' height='30'/>" + count,
                    type: 'alert',
                    template: "<a id='noty' title='Click Here to see all recent alerts' href='alertjquery.html' target='_blank'><div id ='noty_message'><span class='noty_text'></span></div></a>",
                    closeWith: ['button'],
                    dismissQueue: true,
                    timeout: false
                });
```

I used jquery animate to zoom in on the image slightly:

```
 $('noty').hover(function () {


            width = $('.item').width() * zoom;

            height = $('.item').height() * zoom;

            $(this).find('.item').stop(false, true).animate({ 'width': width, 'height': height, 'top': move, 'left': move }, { duration: 300 });


        }
```

What I want to happen is when you hover over the noty marked with the id `noty`, the image inside zooms in slightly. I presume it doesn't matter that I'm using the noty it should work, normally anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `#` to target element by `id`:

```
$('#noty')
```

Also, since your element is dynamically created, you need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

```
$('body').on("hover","#noty",function(){
   //some operation
});
```

Another note is that `hover()` take two handler which is fired when you mouse over and mouse out your element. So you're probably need to handle the case when you mouse out your element as well.

Answer (score 0):

you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(document).on("hover","#noty",function(){
   width = $('.item').width() * zoom;

        height = $('.item').height() * zoom;

        $(this).find('.item').stop(false, true).animate({ 'width': width, 'height': height, 'top': move, 'left': move }, { duration: 300 });
});
```

It helps you to attach handlers for the future elements